# Can you create a virtual filesystem on available space of existing filesystems?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I currently have 4 ext4 disks in my PC. Together they have about 4TB of space available. I want to store a 3 TB image just for a day. Is it possible to create a temporary virtual fs across the available space of the disks.

It is possible for me to move the files around to get the space on a single drive. I'm just wondering if there is a current solution for something like this.

Comment: I assume that no formatting should be involved ?

Do any of these disks have unpartitioned storage ?

Comment: Nope. No unpartioned space. I was thinking of creating a file on each drive with dd and then create a raid stripe across them, but that is just a thought for now, not tried yet.

Comment: In your situation I wolud just use zip-and-split method. If you had unpartitioned 3TB storage you could create one 3TB LVM volume from such configuration connecting it into single LVM logical volume.

Comment: I like @MaciejAsembler 's idea of an image just compressed & split, but I don't know the commands to split it into manageable chunks *and* have them spread across 4 different partitions... maybe create some chunks, manually pause, move chunks, continue, repeat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with `dmsetup`.

### Prepare empty files

```
fallocate -l $((800*1024*1024*1024)) /mnt/disk1/file1
fallocate -l $((1200*1024*1024*1024)) /mnt/disk2/file2
fallocate -l $((1100*1024*1024*1024)) /mnt/disk3/file3
fallocate -l $((200*1024*1024*1024)) /mnt/disk4/file4
```

This example gives `800 GiB`, `1200 GiB`, `1100 GiB` and `200 GiB` in four files – `3300 GiB` in total.

### Prepare loop devices

```
sudo losetup -f /mnt/disk1/file1
sudo losetup -f /mnt/disk2/file2
sudo losetup -f /mnt/disk3/file3
sudo losetup -f /mnt/disk4/file4
```

Check with `sudo losetup -a` which loop devices are associated with your files. My example assumes they are `/dev/loop0`, `/dev/loop1`, `/dev/loop2` and `/dev/loop3` respectively.

### Create logical device

**EDIT: see Xen2050's answer. It gives a simpler way from this point.

My original, more complex way is as follows:**

First you have to know how large your files are in `512 B` unit. In my example these numbers are `800*1024*1024*2`, `1200*1024*1024*2`, `1100*1024*1024*2` and `200*1024*1024*2`; i.e. `1677721600`, `2516582400`, `2306867200` and `419430400`.

You will also need the sum of the first...
zero numbers (trivial): `0`,
one number (trivial): `1677721600`,
two numbers: `1677721600 + 2516582400 = 4194304000`,
three numbers: `1677721600 + 2516582400 + 2306867200 = 6501171200`.

*I hope i did my math right. :)*

Invoke:

```
sudo dmsetup create my_device
```

Now give a proper table (map):

```
0 1677721600 linear /dev/loop0 0
1677721600 2516582400 linear /dev/loop1 0
4194304000 2306867200 linear /dev/loop2 0
6501171200 419430400 linear /dev/loop3 0
```

(Every line starts with a computed sum followed by computed size.)

Press <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> to finish.

### Create filesystem

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/my_device
```

### Mount

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/my_device
sudo mount -o rw /dev/mapper/my_device /mnt/my_device
```

Note that there is less than `3300 GiB` of free space on `my_device` because of the filesystem needs. Adjust the sizes of your files beforehand, depending on available free space on your partitions and your image size.

---

When your job is over:

### Revert

```
sudo umount /mnt/my_device
sudo dmsetup remove my_device
sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0 /dev/loop1 /dev/loop2 /dev/loop3
rm /mnt/disk1/file1 /mnt/disk2/file2 /mnt/disk3/file3 /mnt/disk4/file4
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **`mdadm`** to set up the RAID is another option, similar to Kamil's answer but hopefully without all the math.

Once there's a big file in each partition (`fallocate` looks good) and loop devices set up, then according to the instructions at https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup  (replacing the example `/dev/sdbN` devices with your `/dev/loopN` devices, and `--raid-devices=2` with the number of devices (in your case 4):

1. First - Install mdadm

   - Debian, Ubuntu:  apt-get install mdadm
   - Gentoo: `emerge mdadm`
   - RedHat: `yum install mdadm`

> ## Linear mode
>
> Ok, so you have two or more partitions which are not necessarily the same size (but of course can be), which you want to append to each
>   other.
>
> Spare-disks are not supported here. If a disk dies, the array dies
>   with it. There's no information to put on a spare disk.
>
> Using mdadm, a single command like
>
> ```
> mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=linear --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb6 /dev/sdc5
> ```
>
> should create the array. The parameters talk for themselves. The
>   output might look like this
>
> ```
> mdadm: chunk size defaults to 64K
> mdadm: array /dev/md0 started.
> ```
>
> Have a look in [/proc/mdstat](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Mdstat). You should see that the array is
>   running.
>
> Now, you can create a filesystem, just like you would on any other
>   device, mount it, include it in your /etc/fstab and so on.
>
> ## RAID-0
>
> You have two or more devices, of approximately the same size, and you want to combine their storage capacity and also combine their
>   performance by accessing them in parallel.
>
> ```
> mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=stripe --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb6 /dev/sdc5
> ```
>
> Like in Linear mode, spare disks are not supported here either. RAID-0
>   has no redundancy, so when a disk dies, the array goes with it.
>
> Having run mdadm you have initialised the superblocks and started the
>   raid device. Have a look in [/proc/mdstat](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Mdstat) to see what's going on.
>   You should see that your device is now running.
>
> /dev/md0 is now ready to be formatted, mounted, used and abused.

I don't think you want RAID-0 since in your case every part is on the same drive, and it would probably *slow* access with unnecessary attempted reading from each part at the same time. But seems a more complete answer to include it.

- It also looks important to [Save the RAID configuration](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup#Saving_your_RAID_configuration) too, with the command below. Look at the output (or in the mdadm.conf file) to see the RAID's UUID too.

  `mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`

### Some other useful commands (see `man mdadm`):

- `mdadm --query /dev/md0`   - Examine a device (array or component device ex. /dev/loop1) to see (1) if it is an md device and (2) if it is a component of an md array)
- `mdadm --examine /dev/loop1`   - Print contents of metadata stored on device
- `mdadm --detail /dev/md0`   - Detailed array info, UUID
- `mdadm --stop /dev/md0`   - Stop an array
- `mdadm --assemble --scan`   - Assemble and start all arrays listed in the standard config file (/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf on Ubuntu, Debian? *If* the configuration is saved as above).

  - Will also start all arrays in /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
- `mdadm --scan --assemble --uuid=a26bf396:31389f83:0df1722d:f404fe4c` - Assemble only the array with given UUID.
- `mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/loop1 /dev/loop2 [all devices]`   - Assemble & start, the hard way

---

**LVM** could work too, but from reading https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/index.html and http://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/lvm-configuration-linux/ and `man lvm` it may not be as simple as RAID above. Apparently (?) the lvm commands seem to look at *every* device attached to your computer, so I can see the potential to include the wrong devices by mistake... There's probably a command *somewhere* to get around that...